Incorrect Map java deserialization
I serialze map of objects Map<String, Object> and after succesfull deserialize it as map of maps of objects Map<String, Map<String, Object>>. Seems it is incorrect behaviour, or is there some subtlety that needs to be taken into account?
Below is the test code.
  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Map of objects
    Map<String, Object> singleMap = Map.of("KEY", "VALUE");
    byte[] serializedMap;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
      oos.writeObject(singleMap);
      serializedMap = bos.toByteArray();
    }

    // Map of maps of objects
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> restoredDoubleMap;
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedMap);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
      // I expected exception here but nothing occurs
      restoredDoubleMap = (Map<String, Map<String, Object>>) ois.readObject();
    }

    // This is correct
    assertTrue(restoredDoubleMap instanceof Map<String, Map<String, Object>>);
    
    // But how can it be? 
    assertEquals(singleMap, restoredDoubleMap);

    System.out.println(singleMap); // Output: {KEY=VALUE}
    System.out.println(restoredDoubleMap); // Output: {KEY=VALUE} ???

    // Here we got ClassCastException... but why if it deserealized as map of maps?
    System.out.println(restoredDoubleMap.get("KEY").keySet());
  }


Looks like a type erasure issue to me - https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

the second output is l(logically) the same as the first (the variable is declared as  Map<String, Map<String, Object>>, but the instance is Map<String, Object> [ignoring type erasure]) and you get a ClassCastException since the String (instance type of value) is not a Map<...> (from the variable declaration) - that is the consequence of type erasure and ignoring "Unchecked cast" warnings (maybe worth remembering that a (reference) cast does not change the instance; just a request for the compiler)

BTW you don't need serialization to show that behavior, just use Raw Type (for testing only!): Map<String, Map<String, Object>> restoredDoubleMap = (Map) singleMap;
